# Modal View Not Working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using the following code in my view controller and I want it to present another view controller called "chooserViewController" modaly

```
    - (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self presentModalViewController:chooserViewController animated:YES];
}
```

I am getting a compile error not recognizing "chooserViewController".  Am I doing it wrong?

Update:

```
- (void)add:(id)sender 
{
    RoutineExerciseChooserViewController *routineExerciseChooserViewController = [[RoutineExerciseChooserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RoutineExerciseChooserViewController" bundle: nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:routineExerciseChooserViewController animated:YES];
    [routineExerciseChooserViewController release];
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are doing it wrong. You can't just use a variable named `chooserViewController` without declaring and initializing it first.

Comment: Why exactly do you override the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `chooserViewController`:

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    ChooserViewController *chooserViewController = [[ChooserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChooserView" bundle: nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:chooserViewController animated:YES];
    [chooserViewController release];
}
```

If you're not loading from a nib, obviously you'll use a different way to create `chooserViewController`, but you have to do something to ensure it exists, and can then be presented.

Comment: I edited the code to use initWithNibName:bundle:. I don't think there is an initWithNibName: method available for UIViewControllers.